# Json utc time to local time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I discovered that this URL [api-sunrise-sun sunset](http://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=12.9833&lng=77.5833)  gives date time in UTC format however I want to convert on the fly to local time irrespective where my webpage is opened ! How would I achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried simply $.get it? By the way it is apparently does not provide the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are showing the time after successfully getting the json. Try this:

```
//today's date, or whatever
var t_date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();

//time from json. example: 10:04:34 PM
var t_from_json = response["results"]["sunrise"]

var utc_date = new Date( t_date + " " + t_from_json + " UTC")
//Date 2017-02-21T22:04:34.000Z

//two options:

utc_date.toString();
//"Tue Feb 21 2017 19:04:34 GMT-0300 (CLST)"

var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
utc_date.setMinutes(utc_date.getMinutes() - offset);
//Date 2017-02-21T19:04:34.000Z
```